# Deadbolt, subjectPresent and @this

Tags: playframework, deadbolt-2

So with deadbolt currently, using play framework 2.6.X, it seems that i need to use the @this to import the subjectPresent into my template.

I'm sure "import" is the wrong term, but you understand the concept.

The problem is that the moment I use the @this(), I have to use the class twirl template, not the object. Which means that in my controller that has the method that normally calls the static `render`, I now need to inject that template into my constructor.

Is this really what has to happen? It seems like a lot of excessive work for no gain, or is there a workaround?